# regular expression to find post code?

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the post code from a file, i download from google document like:

```
{  
   'address_components':[  
      {  
         'long_name':'Orrs Walk',
         'short_name':'Orrs Walk',
         'types':[  
            'route'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'South Wharf',
         'short_name':'South Wharf',
         'types':[  
            'locality',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Melbourne City',
         'short_name':'Melbourne',
         'types':[  
            'administrative_area_level_2',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Victoria',
         'short_name':'VIC',
         'types':[  
            'administrative_area_level_1',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Australia',
         'short_name':'AU',
         'types':[  
            'country',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'3006',
         'short_name':'3006',
         'types':[  
            'postal_code'
         ]
      }
   ],
   'formatted_address':'Orrs Walk, South Wharf VIC 3006, Australia',
   'geometry':{  
      'bounds':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.8236993,
            'lng':144.9560253
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-37.8250865,
            'lng':144.9523143
         }
      },
      'location':{  
         'lat':-37.8247832,
         'lng':144.9541924
      },
      'location_type':'GEOMETRIC_CENTER',
      'viewport':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.8230439197085,
            'lng':144.9560253
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-37.8257418802915,
            'lng':144.9523143
         }
      }
   },
   'place_id':'ChIJb1iRdFdd1moReZ57m5XraDk',
   'types':[  
      'route'
   ]
},
{  
   'address_components':[  
      {  
         'long_name':'South Wharf',
         'short_name':'South Wharf',
         'types':[  
            'locality',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Melbourne City',
         'short_name':'Melbourne',
         'types':[  
            'administrative_area_level_2',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Victoria',
         'short_name':'VIC',
         'types':[  
            'administrative_area_level_1',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Australia',
         'short_name':'AU',
         'types':[  
            'country',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'3006',
         'short_name':'3006',
         'types':[  
            'postal_code'
         ]
      }
   ],
   'formatted_address':'South Wharf VIC 3006, Australia',
   'geometry':{  
      'bounds':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.8230788,
            'lng':144.9566558
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-37.8276482,
            'lng':144.9475157
         }
      },
      'location':{  
         'lat':-37.825,
         'lng':144.952
      },
      'location_type':'APPROXIMATE',
      'viewport':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.8230788,
            'lng':144.9566558
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-37.8276482,
            'lng':144.9475157
         }
      }
   },
   'place_id':'ChIJ1YQ5tfdn1moRAAGNIXVWBAU',
   'types':[  
      'locality',
      'political'
   ]
},
{  
   'address_components':[  
      {  
         'long_name':'Melbourne',
         'short_name':'Melbourne',
         'types':[  
            'colloquial_area',
            'locality',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Victoria',
         'short_name':'VIC',
         'types':[  
            'administrative_area_level_1',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Australia',
         'short_name':'AU',
         'types':[  
            'country',
            'political'
         ]
      }
   ],
   'formatted_address':'Melbourne VIC, Australia',
   'geometry':{  
      'bounds':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.5112737,
            'lng':145.5125288
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-38.4338593,
            'lng':144.5937418
         }
      },
      'location':{  
         'lat':-37.8136276,
         'lng':144.9630576
      },
      'location_type':'APPROXIMATE',
      'viewport':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.5112737,
            'lng':145.5125288
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-38.4338593,
            'lng':144.5937418
         }
      }
   },
   'place_id':'ChIJ90260rVG1moRkM2MIXVWBAQ',
   'types':[  
      'colloquial_area',
      'locality',
      'political'
   ]
},
{  
   'address_components':[  
      {  
         'long_name':'3006',
         'short_name':'3006',
         'types':[  
            'postal_code'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'South Wharf',
         'short_name':'South Wharf',
         'types':[  
            'locality',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Victoria',
         'short_name':'VIC',
         'types':[  
            'administrative_area_level_1',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Australia',
         'short_name':'AU',
         'types':[  
            'country',
            'political'
         ]
      }
   ],
   'formatted_address':'South Wharf VIC 3006, Australia',
   'geometry':{  
      'bounds':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.8192449,
            'lng':144.971423
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-37.8314821,
            'lng':144.946908
         }
      },
      'location':{  
         'lat':-37.8245483,
         'lng':144.963937
      },
      'location_type':'APPROXIMATE',
      'viewport':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.8192449,
            'lng':144.971423
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-37.8314821,
            'lng':144.946908
         }
      }
   },
   'place_id':'ChIJb3SLlEdd1moR0DkuRnhWBBw',
   'postcode_localities':[  
      'South Wharf',
      'Southbank'
   ],
   'types':[  
      'postal_code'
   ]
},
{  
   'address_components':[  
      {  
         'long_name':'Melbourne City',
         'short_name':'Melbourne',
         'types':[  
            'administrative_area_level_2',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Victoria',
         'short_name':'VIC',
         'types':[  
            'administrative_area_level_1',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Australia',
         'short_name':'AU',
         'types':[  
            'country',
            'political'
         ]
      }
   ],
   'formatted_address':'Melbourne, VIC, Australia',
   'geometry':{  
      'bounds':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.7754505,
            'lng':144.9913306
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-37.8506672,
            'lng':144.8969813
         }
      },
      'location':{  
         'lat':-37.8100512,
         'lng':144.9281496
      },
      'location_type':'APPROXIMATE',
      'viewport':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.7754505,
            'lng':144.9913306
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-37.8506672,
            'lng':144.8969813
         }
      }
   },
   'place_id':'ChIJv_FYgkNd1moRpxLuRXZURFs',
   'types':[  
      'administrative_area_level_2',
      'political'
   ]
},
{  
   'address_components':[  
      {  
         'long_name':'CBD & South Melbourne',
         'short_name':'CBD & South Melbourne',
         'types':[  
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Melbourne',
         'short_name':'Melbourne',
         'types':[  
            'colloquial_area',
            'locality',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Victoria',
         'short_name':'VIC',
         'types':[  
            'administrative_area_level_1',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Australia',
         'short_name':'AU',
         'types':[  
            'country',
            'political'
         ]
      }
   ],
   'formatted_address':'CBD & South Melbourne, Melbourne VIC, Australia',
   'geometry':{  
      'bounds':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.7730008,
            'lng':145.0158347
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-37.8574821,
            'lng':144.8969813
         }
      },
      'location':{  
         'lat':-37.8362164,
         'lng':144.9501708
      },
      'location_type':'APPROXIMATE',
      'viewport':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.7730008,
            'lng':145.0158347
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-37.8574821,
            'lng':144.8969813
         }
      }
   },
   'place_id':'ChIJORuuCkxd1moRNMrml7yk-C8',
   'types':[  
      'political'
   ]
},
{  
   'address_components':[  
      {  
         'long_name':'Melbourne Metropolitan Area',
         'short_name':'Melbourne Metropolitan Area',
         'types':[  
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Victoria',
         'short_name':'VIC',
         'types':[  
            'administrative_area_level_1',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Australia',
         'short_name':'AU',
         'types':[  
            'country',
            'political'
         ]
      }
   ],
   'formatted_address':'Melbourne Metropolitan Area, VIC, Australia',
   'geometry':{  
      'bounds':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.4017502,
            'lng':146.1925247
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-38.4999344,
            'lng':144.4440773
         }
      },
      'location':{  
         'lat':-37.8001063,
         'lng':145.3143491
      },
      'location_type':'APPROXIMATE',
      'viewport':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-37.4017502,
            'lng':146.1925247
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-38.4999344,
            'lng':144.4440773
         }
      }
   },
   'place_id':'ChIJmYjB3BaF1moRtCmV8wIoZQU',
   'types':[  
      'political'
   ]
},
{  
   'address_components':[  
      {  
         'long_name':'Victoria',
         'short_name':'VIC',
         'types':[  
            'administrative_area_level_1',
            'political'
         ]
      },
      {  
         'long_name':'Australia',
         'short_name':'AU',
         'types':[  
            'country',
            'political'
         ]
      }
   ],
   'formatted_address':'Victoria, Australia',
   'geometry':{  
      'bounds':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-33.9806474,
            'lng':150.0169685
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-39.18316069999999,
            'lng':140.9616819
         }
      },
      'location':{  
         'lat':-37.4713077,
         'lng':144.7851531
      },
      'location_type':'APPROXIMATE',
      'viewport':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-33.9806474,
            'lng':149.9764884
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-39.1590935,
            'lng':140.9616819
         }
      }
   },
   'place_id':'ChIJT5UYfksx1GoRNJWCvuL8Tlo',
   'types':[  
      'administrative_area_level_1',
      'political'
   ]
},
{  
   'address_components':[  
      {  
         'long_name':'Australia',
         'short_name':'AU',
         'types':[  
            'country',
            'political'
         ]
      }
   ],
   'formatted_address':'Australia',
   'geometry':{  
      'bounds':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-9.187026399999999,
            'lng':159.2872223
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-54.83376579999999,
            'lng':110.9510339
         }
      },
      'location':{  
         'lat':-25.274398,
         'lng':133.775136
      },
      'location_type':'APPROXIMATE',
      'viewport':{  
         'northeast':{  
            'lat':-0.6911343999999999,
            'lng':166.7429167
         },
         'southwest':{  
            'lat':-51.66332320000001,
            'lng':100.0911072
         }
      }
   },
   'place_id':'ChIJ38WHZwf9KysRUhNblaFnglM',
   'types':[  
      'country',
      'political'
   ]
}
]
```

i need extract the post code, `'short_name': '3006'`,but not all short_name followed with a post code

I have tired some ways, but I just acquire some spaces, I had used strip to word

```
import re

hand = open('data')

for line in hand:
    #print line
    line = line.rstrip()

    stuff = re.findall('^\'short_name\':([0-9]+)',line)
    print stuff
```

and I get the result like that:

```
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I fixed it, like that: there are too many space among them,

```
import re

hand = open('data')
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()

    stuff = re.findall(r'\'short_name\':\s*\'([0-9]{4})\'',line)
    #stuff = re.findall(r'\'short_name\':([0-9]{4})',line)
    print stuff
```

Comment: So. what have you tried?

Comment: Why not parsing the json directly?

Comment: Did you try anything ? Please show what you have tried.

Comment: This is obviously not the best approach, but in your code, try `re.findall(r'\'short_name\':([0-9]+)',line)` - Remove the `^` at the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque it still unwork

Answer (score 1):

The data that you are dealing with looks like JSON, but it is not - because of the single quotes (JSON required double quotes).

Assuming `fileContent` is the content of your file (a string, as shown in your question), you can convert it to a Python data structure and then search as a list of dictionaries:

```
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval(fileContent)
codes = [[field['short_name'] for field in entry['address_components'] 
          if 'postal_code' in field['types']]
         for entry in data]
#[['3006'], ['3006'], [], ['3006'], [], [], [], [], []]
```

You can extract any other information from this list as well.

Answer (score -4):

```
'[a-z]++_[a-z]++':'([0-9]++)'
```

watch out for spaces if any present in mid.

Comment: How on Earth is this an answer?